# How to read iPhone files without jailbreaking?

Tags: iphone, ssh

I'd like to access files in an iPhone, such as using remotely connecting via ssh and telnet. But it appears that the iPhone's ssh or telnet are not supported. I can ping it, but cannot use telnet or ssh.

I read through some internet article, it appears that using jailbreak or Cydia it is doable, but I guess it would break my iPhone's license.

Is there an official way to ssh or telnet into my iPhone?

Comment: Why people give -ve vote to this question? I don't see anything problem with it. :-)

Comment: No programming angle so far I guess...

Comment: I'm not sure it counts as offensive either.

Comment: Jailbreaking just voids your warranty, which IMO is very worth it. The iPhone/iPod Touch is a computer, not just an mp3 player, but it is very limited from its potential. Jailbreaking is for people who know what they're doing and want the full use of their product. Doing it to steal cracked apps is for criminals, but that doesn't make jailbreaking in general illegal and it doesn't make anything wrong with just jailbreaking. Apple should have a dev version of iPhone firmwares that allow you to do whatever you can do on a normal mac, like ssh, third party apps, etc.

Comment: Imagine your Mac/PC with the same limitations as the iPhone.

Comment: Yes you can. Just download [iPhone Folders](http://iphonefolders.com/).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about apple products, so belongs on apple.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 12):

You can't just access any file in a non-jailbroken iPhone.

You can access data files for your own programs during development using Xcode's Organizer, go to Devices -> your iphone -> Summary -> Applications -> your app, click on the triangle thingy to show the Application Data, which you can download.

Otherwise use something like Airsharing (see moogs' answer which came as I was writing this) to upload&download a bunch of files.

Comment: don't care how old the answer is, this was EXTREMELY helpful.  upvote for sure.

Comment: still missing the "you can't have a ssh or telnet daemon on iPhone without jailbreaking it, because Apple don't want to and it won't allow any app to do it", but that mostly answers.

Answer (score 4):

I loved ssh-ing before, but [Airsharing](http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=289943355&mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D6) is even better. You can upload files via a wifi connection to your ipod (using a browser or via webDAV). It was free for the first few weeks, but now it goes for $4.99. That's still not bad.
You can view office, image, pdf and html files.

(I'm not affiliated with airsharing, just a happy user :) )

Comment: Reading a file in the iphone from a desktop PC? Yes.

Comment: i meant the reverse way, copy file from iphone to desktop. Can I ?

Comment: I clicked the link for Airsharing and the iTunes store popped up with "The item you've requested is not currently available in the U.S. store. I think it's region locked. Are there other tools I might be able to use?

Answer (score 3):

No you can't.  You have to jailbreak to do that.

Answer (score 3):

Even when not jailbroken, you can access some part of the filesystem with [iPhone Broswer](http://code.google.com/p/iphonebrowser/)

Answer (score 2):

I was very surprised and please with [iPhone Explorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iphoneexplorer/). It's one of those softwares that just work and needs nothing installed on the iPhone, but it will give full file access if your iphone is jailbroken.

Now, of course ideally we'd install something on the iPhone without needing anything on the computer and access files on the iPhone like a pen drive (and unlike some apps that do that but only through HTTP and wi-fi), but this is fairly good enough. And it's free! Because they use it to promote their other apps, and file exploring on iPhone is nearly useless for most users anyway.

There's just no way jose in hell to access **all** files in the iPhone without jailbreaking. Period. Apple have never allowed it.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `iFile` I have tried all the others and this one is my favourites.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with iFunbox, but  you dont have access to edit, move , delete the system files , so you dont have full access to have full access you need to jailbreak your iDevice.